# How to make files invisible when listing files inside zip files?

Tags: 20.04, password, archive, zip

Because when i executed

```
unzip -l mantap.zip
```

it still showed below:

```
Archive:  mantap.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      116  2020-10-01 06:04   mantap.cpp
---------                     -------
      116                     1 file
```

I don't want file mantap.cpp visible here. Can anyone tell me please?

Comment: The *purpose* of the `unzip` command's `-l` option is to list the files contained in the archive... I'm confused why you are executing it if you don't want to do that? what information **do** you want, exactly?

Comment: See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290088/330980

Comment: Try P7zip Archive format 7z.`sudo apt install p7zip`